# Too many character literals in MVC View

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, viewbag

**Question Background:**

I pass to my MVC view a ViewBag object which contain a list of items. These items are then added through the use of a For loop to a Javascript method called 'AddRows' which creates and adds a new HTML row to a table in the view.

**The issue:**

This code has worked before but I have run into an issue where I'm getting the following error:

[image]

**The code:**

```
 @foreach (var cartItem in (List<LoginTest.Models.CartItem>)ViewBag.Data)
{

        var cartItemId = '@cartItem.CartItemId';
        var cartImage = '@cartItem.CartItemImage';
        var cartItemName = '@cartItem.CartItemName';
        var cartBrand = '@cartItem.CartItemBrand';
        var cartItemPrice = '@cartItem.CartItemPrice';
        var cartItemCartItemQty = '@cartItem.CartItemQty';

        AddRows(cartItemId, cartImage, cartItemName, cartBrand, cartItemPrice, cartItemCartItemQty);
}


 <script type="text/javascript">

    var AddRows = function (productId, productImage, productName, productBrand, productPrice, productQty) {

        var button = '<input class="btn btn-primary btn-block deleteItem" type="button" value="Remove"/>';
        var image = '<img src="/Images/' + productImage + '" class="productCartImage"/>';
        var selectors = '<input id="demo1" class="touchSpin" type="text" value="' + productQty + '" name="demo1">';


        var $html = $('<tr class="item">' +
            '<td class="prodId" style="display:none;">' + productId + '</td>' +
            '<td class="prodImage hidden-xs">' + image + '</td>' +
            '<td class="prodName">' + productName + '</td>' +
            '<td class="prodBrand">' + productBrand + '</td>' +
            '<td class="prodPrice"> £' + productPrice + '</td>' +
            '<td class="prodQty TableCell">' + selectors + '</td>' +
            '<td>' + button + '</td>' +
            '</tr>');

        $html.find("input[name='demo1']").TouchSpin({
            min: 1,
            max: 100,
            step: 1,
        });

        $('#Table1 > tbody:last').append($html);



    };
</script>
```

**What I have tried so far:**

1. Tried changing the single quote around each property of the item in the list from a single quote to a double. This will sort the string literal issue but then creates an error saying that the AddRows methed cannot be found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

```
@foreach (var cartItem in (List<LoginTest.Models.CartItem>)ViewBag.Data)
{

    var cartItemId = '@cartItem.CartItemId';
    var cartImage = '@cartItem.CartItemImage';
    var cartItemName = '@cartItem.CartItemName';
    var cartBrand = '@cartItem.CartItemBrand';
    var cartItemPrice = '@cartItem.CartItemPrice';
    var cartItemCartItemQty = '@cartItem.CartItemQty';

    AddRows(cartItemId, cartImage, cartItemName, cartBrand, cartItemPrice, cartItemCartItemQty);
}
```

Use this

```
@foreach (var cartItem in (List<LoginTest.Models.CartItem>)ViewBag.Data)
{
<text>
    var cartItemId = '@cartItem.CartItemId';
    var cartImage = '@cartItem.CartItemImage';
    var cartItemName = '@cartItem.CartItemName';
    var cartBrand = '@cartItem.CartItemBrand';
    var cartItemPrice = '@cartItem.CartItemPrice';
    var cartItemCartItemQty = '@cartItem.CartItemQty';

    AddRows(cartItemId, cartImage, cartItemName, cartBrand, cartItemPrice, cartItemCartItemQty);
</text>
}
```

the `<text>` element tell Razor that the code shouldn't be considered as C#

Comment: Many thanks! I've realised that I originally had the for loop in a <script> tag but took it out! Again thanks for helping me solve this.

Answer (score 1):

Relocate this js variable declaration block inside script and force **Razor** interprite it as text with `<text>` tag. Like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

@foreach (var cartItem in (List<LoginTest.Models.CartItem>)ViewBag.Data)
{
     <text>
        var cartItemId = '@cartItem.CartItemId';
        var cartImage = '@cartItem.CartItemImage';
        var cartItemName = '@cartItem.CartItemName';
        var cartBrand = '@cartItem.CartItemBrand';
        var cartItemPrice = '@cartItem.CartItemPrice';
        var cartItemCartItemQty = '@cartItem.CartItemQty';

        AddRows(cartItemId, cartImage, cartItemName, cartBrand, cartItemPrice, cartItemCartItemQty);
    </text>
}



    var AddRows = function (productId, productImage, productName, productBrand, productPrice, productQty) {

        var button = '<input class="btn btn-primary btn-block deleteItem" type="button" value="Remove"/>';
        var image = '<img src="/Images/' + productImage + '" class="productCartImage"/>';
        var selectors = '<input id="demo1" class="touchSpin" type="text" value="' + productQty + '" name="demo1">';


        var $html = $('<tr class="item">' +
            '<td class="prodId" style="display:none;">' + productId + '</td>' +
            '<td class="prodImage hidden-xs">' + image + '</td>' +
            '<td class="prodName">' + productName + '</td>' +
            '<td class="prodBrand">' + productBrand + '</td>' +
            '<td class="prodPrice"> £' + productPrice + '</td>' +
            '<td class="prodQty TableCell">' + selectors + '</td>' +
            '<td>' + button + '</td>' +
            '</tr>');

        $html.find("input[name='demo1']").TouchSpin({
            min: 1,
            max: 100,
            step: 1,
        });

        $('#Table1 > tbody:last').append($html);



    };
</script>
```